# How to find AD user with firstname and lastname?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

How can i find users samaccountname with firstname and lastname?

```
$users =
@'
LastName;FirstName;
Roy;Adam
Smith;George
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ";"

ForEach ($User in $Users) {
  Get-ADUser -Filter {GivenName -like $user.firstname -and Surname -like $user.lastname} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty sAMaccountName 
}
```

im getting an error

```
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (:) [Get-ADUser], ArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Comment: You're using a filtering syntax that the AD Module does not like. Change your filter to a string: `-Filter "GivenName -like '$($user.firstname)' -and Surname -like '$($user.lastname)'"` // also, you seem to be searching for exact values so, I would use `-eq` instead of `-like`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property access operation inside the `{...}` filter block won't resolve correctly.

Use a string-based filter instead:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "GivenName -like '$($user.firstname)' -and Surname -like '$($user.lastname)'" |...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$users =
@'
LastName;FirstName;
Roy;Adam
Smith;George
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ";"    
ForEach ($User in $Users) {
  Get-ADUser -Filter {GivenName -match $user.firstname -and Surname -match $user.lastname} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty sAMaccountName 
}
```

Comment: The AD filter does not have a `-match` operator.